# Scala in-line append with comparison and loop

Tags: scala, foreach, comparison

I am looking for the Scala syntax for appending to an ArrayBuffer using a comparison. I have two arrays of two different types so I cannot simply use an intersection. In essence this is what I am looking for:

```
val allPeople : ArrayBuffer[Person] = ...
val result = ArrayBuffer[Person]()
val acceptableAges : ArrayBuffer[Age] = ...

// Simplify below
for (p <- allPeople if acceptableAges.indexof(p.age) >= 0) 
    result.append(p)
```

Is there a sleek solution to this? New to Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid using mutable variables as much as you can(which takes time but question yourself everytime you see mutable `var`). There is **scala** and **fp** for a reason.

What you are looking for is a `.filter` function.

Here goes example,

```
scala> final case class Age(age: Int)
defined class Age

scala> final case class Person(name: String, age: Age)
defined class Person
```

Given:

```
scala> val allPeople = List(Person("prayagupd", Age(100)), Person("steven wilson", Age(200)))
allPeople: List[Person] = List(Person(prayagupd,Age(100)), Person(steven wilson,Age(200)))

scala> val acceptableAges : List[Age] = List(Age(100), Age(150))
acceptableAges: List[Age] = List(Age(100), Age(150))
```

use `.filter` to **filter** your data:

```
scala> allPeople.filter(p => acceptableAges.contains(p.age))
res2: List[Person] = List(Person(prayagupd,Age(100)))
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I agree. I am coming from C++ so I am running into issues left and right that can be solved using functional programming. Still learning. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I totally understand but its very worth following a practice not to use mutable in scala. Welcome to FP and scala. I can tell you its a very good community